# django object is not getting created after posting data through form

Tags: python, django

I am practicing django by making a simple app. so, i am facing a problem in assigning a object to a variable(sorry i dont know how to write this in words). First i took values in html form then passed it to a view where i am assigning all those values to a object variable of a model.
The code is like this:-
View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Customer,Order
from pizza.models import item

def order(request):
    customer = Customer.objects.all()
    items=item.objects.all()

    context={'customer':customer,'items':items}
    return render(request,'pizza/order.html',context)
def profile(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        cusname_=request.POST['cusname']
        cusphone_=request.POST['cusphone']
        cusaddress_=request.POST['cusaddress']

  cus=Customer.objects.get_or_create(cus_name=cusname_,cus_phone=cusphone_,cus_address=cusaddress_)
        item_list=request.POST.getlist('check')

        context={'cus':cus}

        return render(request, 'pizza/profile.html', context)


Html:-
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>order time</h1>
<form method="post" action=" {% url "profile" %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="name">Customer Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="cusname" id="name"  placeholder="enter name">
    <label for="phone">phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="cusphone" id="phone"  placeholder="enter phone">
    <label for="address">address</label>
    <input type="text" name="cusaddress" id="address"  placeholder="enter address"><br>

    {% for item in items %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="item{{ item.id }}" value="{{ item.item_name }}">
        <label for="item{{ item.id }}">{{ item.item_name }}={{ item.item_price }}</label>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" placeholder="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see i am declaring a object variable "cus" in profile view but it is not getting declared.As if i pass cus as a context in another template for use , i cant use it there.

Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>profile</p>

<p>{{ cus.cus_name }}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here cus.cus_name is not getting printed on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_or_create will create your object successfully. But it returns a tuple instead of object. It will retrun (object, isCreated) where object is the newly created or updated object and isCreated will return True or False depending the object is newly created or not.

So change your code like this

```
cus, isCreated =Customer.objects.get_or_create(cus_name=cusname_,cus_phone=cusphone_,cus_address=cusaddress_)
```

Comment: actually the first way worked but if i refresh and add another entry,then also it does not print it . Yes, the entry does not get saved twice which is ok but i have restart the host website to enter another entry.otherwise it does not print it on next page

Comment: You need not restart the host website to add another entry.  get_or_create returns the object even when object is not created. It will give you the existing object.

Comment: oh ok...thanks for the help. I used a anchor tag to navigate to the previous page instead of refreshing and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save it to your database instead assigning to a variable

```
Customer(cus_name=cusname_,cus_phone=cusphone_,cus_address=cusaddress_).save()
```

Comment: i read in documentation that objects.get_or_create does not need .save() and i checked in admin site too. The data i entered is getting saved there without use of save().

Comment: My bad, I changed it